# "y_rotation" not working?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So once I was inspired by some game on another platform to make it's parkour moves in minecraft. I knew that without commands, I was not able to do it. Luckily, I have done some commands before and thought that it was possible with the command `/execute`.

Some time later after experimenting with commands to come up with how to boost the player up, i run into a problem.

I decide to make it a little more realistic by making sure that the player only jumped high when he/she was looking up. So of course, I try this command:

`/execute at @p[y_rotation=-90] as @p[y_rotation=-90] if block ~ ~-0.01 ~ minecraft:stone run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 10`

I tried it, but it seemed that it did not run the command when I was looking up. Since i'm a person that was discouraged from trying other choices, I came here to ask,

What is the command?

Comment: "thought that it was possible with the command /execute" I recommend reading or watching a commands tutorial. `/execute` does absolutely nothing on its own. If your thought process of doing something in Minecraft starts with `/execute`, you're planning wrong. Also, your selector is redundant and would even cause problems once you start using `@a`. Better: `execute as @p[y_rotation=-90] at @s`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the *x axis* if you want to test for players looking up/down. Testing for y is for players looking left or right.

So this will work (tested with 1.13.2):

`/execute at @p[x_rotation=-90] as @p[x_rotation=-90] if block ~ ~-0.01 ~ minecraft:stone run effect give @s minecraft:levitation 1 10`

---

Edit to clarify:

This is not a bug. You just need to think of the axis to be threaded and try to screw it in somewhere:

[image]

If you rotate X the player will look up or down and rotating Y will let them look left or right.

Comment: That's very strange. It was reported as a bug, but closed as "invalid": https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-124405

Comment: @FabianRöling that is because it's not a bug :P